# How to link with Paypal from our website?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When the user signed up on the website (new account) then I would like to give the user the opportunity to link Paypal account on our website so that they can make an order using Paypal payment method.

Is this the correct API documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/ or I'm I looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Log in with PayPal is for logging in. If you want payments for orders, use Checkout with PayPal.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server